# Can't render the same components twice on the same page

Tags: reactjs

I have a time range component like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TimeRangePicker from 'react-time-range-picker';

export default class TimeRange extends Component {

 

  pickerupdate = (start_time, end_time) => {
    // start and end time in 24hour time
    console.log(`start time: ${start_time}, end time: ${end_time}`)
  }

  render() {



    return (
      <div style={{marginBottom:"60px"}}>
          <TimeRangePicker hourmarkers hourlines markercolor="black" key={this.props.id} timeupdate={this.pickerupdate}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

On another page, I'm trying to render the component twice. But it's appearing only once properly and I'm just getting an outline in the 2nd case.

I tried adding the key but that is not working as well.

Could someone help me here?

Comment: I had a look through the [source code](https://github.com/AlexanderCollins/react-time-range-picker). They are using an id on the canvas and getting the canvas with the id by using [`getElementById`](https://github.com/AlexanderCollins/react-time-range-picker/blob/master/src/index.js#L189). It'll only return the first element. so, don't think you can use two of them in the same page.

Comment: It could be the 3rd party component itself.  [When testing this](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-shape-s3exog?file=/src/App.js) the first thing I notice is that the 3rd party component uses a hard-coded `id` for their markup.  So (1) it creates invalid markup when used more than once and (2) any functionality which targets that `id` will only ever target the first matching element on the page.  This may be something you'd need to take up with the vendor, or find a different vendor.